# T-SQL select statement...SUM and HAVING issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table similar to below...

I need to add the values of each row with the exact same date.
(For example the first two rows will equal '5', next two, '5', next two, '8')

```
StoretCode   LocName    ParName   DateTime       Value
95010-A-9    AB 901_4   On Line   201305160000   1
NULL         AB 905_8   On Line   201305160000   4
95010-A-9    AB 901_4   On Line   201305170000   2
NULL         AB 905_8   On Line   201305170000   3
95010-A-9    AB 901_4   On Line   201305180000   4
NULL         AB 905_8   On Line   201305180000   4
```

The result should also have a new LocName...so it should look like...

```
StoretCode   LocName  ParName  DateTime      Value
95010-A-9    AERBAS   On Line  201305160000  5
95010-A-9    AERBAS   On Line  201305170000  5
95010-A-9    AERBAS   On Line  201305180000  8
```

I have tried...

```
Select 'AB 901_4','AB 905_8', Sum(Value)
from dbo.DATA
```

but the results were as expected...one row with a total of all rows...

Also tried.....

```
Select 'AB 901_4','AB 905_8', Sum(Value)
from dbo.DATA
Where LocName, DateTime = LocName, DateTime
```

but result was...

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

tried several others but result was similar to non-boolean msg above...

Comment: Where does the new LocName come from? Is it a constant value that all rows will get or does it depend on the original value?

Comment: I'm sorry...I will need to create the new LocName and delete the rows that were added together...

Comment: Why don't you group by datetime. 
Select 'AB 901_4','AB 905_8', Sum(Value)
from dbo.DATA Group by [DateTime]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines?

```
Select 
  max(StoretCode), 
  'AERBAS' as Locname, 
  max(ParName), 
  DateTime, 
  Sum(Value)
from dbo.DATA
group by DateTime
order by DateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select StoretCode , 'AERBAS' as LocName , ParName , DATA.DateTime, datecount.count as [value]
from dbo.DATA 
join ( select DateTime, count(*) as count from dbo.DATA group by DateTime ) datecount 
  on data.DateTime = datecount.DateTime 
where date.StoretCode is not null
```

If you want a hard coded value for LocName then 'LocName'

Comment: Thanks, but that groups everything by StoretCode and removed the 'Value' column name...the actual table I am working on has 74 distinct StoretCodes...I want to add the rows with the LocNames I mentioned.

Comment: Don't know how to help you as this answers the question as I understand it.

Comment: How is this output different from the desired output?

Comment: To be a little more specific...I am actually working on a table with 74 StoretCodes (including the NULL), 95 LocNames (so many have NULL StoretCodes)...I need to combine the two LocNames I mentioned in my example...

Comment: Against the posted sample data does this query produce the correct results or not?   Not clear to me what combine the two LocNames means.